# ffmpeg random images from video but in order

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg

Ok, so I am using linux, and I have ffmpeg working, coding videos and making the image

But what I would like is to make ffmpeg make up to 10 images from the video.

I was wondering how I would do this. currently I use the following for images.

```
//execute ffmepg to get picture
    exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -vframes 1 -ss ".$time_in_seconds." -i converted_vids/".$name.".".$type." video_images/".$name."_%02d.jpg -y 2> log/image_".$name.".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally following command is used to generate images from video:

```
//d is number of images you create from video
ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg

//like
ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%10.jpg
//would produce 10 images from the video

Hope it's helpful to you
```

Comment: mmm interesting, I tried that without the d and it did not work, just trying it now with the d and see what happens

Comment: with the d at the end it added 10 (0000000001) at the end of the file